# Increase memory-limit Composer doesn't work

Tags: symfony, composer-php, mamp, php-ini, memory-limit

I'm trying to require the bundle in my Symfony project: FOSUserBundle. But it doesn't work, apparently I have to increase the memory_limit. But I can't make it work.

I've already tried to look for the php.ini file to change the memory_limit. But there is no php.ini file in my Symfony project. Why is it not there? Have I forgotten to install something? And if I want to add it manually, where can I put it? There are PHP.INI files in the MAMP folder. I've tried to change the memory_limit value, doesn't help.

And I've tried to run this in the terminal after navigating to the right project folder: php -d memory_limit=2G composer update.
The reaction I get is more or less this:

```
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
```

Here is the error I get after trying to require the bundle:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in...

As you might see, I'm new to Symfony and Composer. Can you please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post output of `composer --version`

Comment: Thanks! Here is the output: Composer version 1.9.0 2019-08-02 20:55:32

Comment: Have you tried `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update` ? https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

Comment: `php -d memory_limit=-1 $(which composer) update`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things which will help a lot.

1. Ensure you are running the latest version of Composer.
2. Ensure you are running at least a recent version of PHP - version 7 improved the memory use substantially - sometimes halving the amount of memory used. Versions 7.2 or (better) 7.3 should be the versions being used now (summer 2019).
3. Actively limit the number of different versions of packages that Composer must check to see what could be valid to use.

   - [Roave/SecurityAdvisories](https://github.com/Roave/SecurityAdvisories) is a good start. This will also stop you installing versions of packages that have known security issues. It will also limit the search-space for valid packages, allowing Composer to ignore large swathes of possible packages, meaning that it does not need to hold large amounts of data for the various potential combinations.
   - You can add other versions of packages to further narrow the search-space. For example, you may have a number of wildcard "*" versions (also known as 'The Death Star Version Constraint') - which are almost always a bad idea. Mostly, a version number of the form "^3.4" or "^4.3" would be better - allowing upgrades from bug-fix versions and features (the 3rd and 2nd numbers), but not major versions, which can often contain breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks! I checked everything, without success :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the composer_memory_limit in the composer.json file under the 'config' part:

"COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT": "2G"